# Android, Espresso: How check if tag value contains some string?

Tags: android-espresso

I want to test if imageView with id **imageViewTour**  and tag that contains **some_text** is displayed.

My test:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.imageViewTour), withTagValue(containsString("some_text")))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

But I get compile error:

```
withTagValue (org.hamcrest.Matchers<java.lang.Object) in ViewMatchers cannot be applied to (org.hamcrest.Matcer<java.lang<String>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 onView(allOf(withId(R.id.imageViewTour), withTagValue(is((Object) "some_text")))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: Also I need to check is tag value is end with "some_string". How I can do this?